# How can I get the FileAttachment from a Message instead of the Attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

First of all, thank you for taking the time to read my question!

I need to retrieve the 'ContentByte' of an attachment of a message.

I use the [Microsoft.Graph SDK for dotnet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).
I retrieve a message, then I take the Message.Body.Content (is html) and show it in an Iframe. In order to show the attachments (cid:...) I have to get them in the Message.Attachments. But there is my problem. The mail attachments have a FileAttachment type with a 'ContentByte' property that I can use to show the attachments. The problem is that the SDK doesn't use the type 'FileAttachment' for Message.Attachments but 'Attachment', which doesn't have a 'ContentByte' property.

Here is my code:

```
Message data = await graphClient.Me
                .Messages[messageId]
                .Request().GetAsync();
```

and

```
var base64 = message.Attachments.Where(c => c.ContentId == contentId).ContentByte;
```

When I explore 'data' with the debugger I can see all the fields from the FileAttachment with all the correct data. But when I try to access it with the second line I get a red line under 'ContentId' because the property doesn't exist for an attachment.

Is this a bug, a mistake in the 'Message' class or do I have to specify somewhere that I want to keep the 'FileAttachment' type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior since `Message.Attachments` returns the collection of [`Attachment` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/attachment?view=graph-rest-1.0).
To get the list of file attachments, filter could be applied by [`FileAttachment` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) via [`OfType` Linq method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
//request message with attachments
var message = await graphClient.Me
      .Messages[messageId]
      .Request().Expand("Attachments").GetAsync();
//filter by file attachments and return first one
var fileAttachment = message.Attachments.OfType<FileAttachment>()
      .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentId == contentId);

if (fileAttachment != null)
{
     var base64 = fileAttachment.ContentBytes;
     //...
}
```